# How to check that a dataframe consists of all 0 entries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I know one way is to loop through all the columns, e.g.,

```
for col in df.columns:
  assert (df[col] != 0).sum() == 0
```

Is there better approach that can operate on the entire dataframe without looping through each individual column?

Comment: @Mark ah right, I think it should be `!=` and not `==`

Comment: This proved to be an interesting question...

Answer (score 3):

Out of curiosity I time tested the methods in the answers given here and that I found to similar questions elsewhere on StackOverflow. Here are the methods:

```py
funcs = { 
    'tdelaney' : lambda df:not df.any(axis=None),
    'Goku 1'   : lambda df:(df == 0).all(axis=None),
    'Goku 2'   : lambda df:all((df == 0).all()),
    'kevin41'  : lambda df:(0 == df.to_numpy()).all(),
    'other 1'  : lambda df:not np.any(df),
    'other 2'  : lambda df:(df != 0).sum().sum() == 0,
    'other 3'  : lambda df:(df != 0).any(axis=None)
}
```

For testing I used a dataframe of 1000 rows and 1000 columns with all zeros and three others with `1` values at `[1,1]`, `[499,499]` and `[999,999]`:

```py
N = 1000
df0 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([N,N]))
df_low = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([N,N]))
df_mid = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([N,N]))
df_high = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([N,N]))
df_low.loc[1, 1] = 1
df_mid.loc[N//2-1, N//2-1] = 1
df_high.loc[N-1, N-1] = 1
```

I then iterated the functions and dataframes in a loop (the prints are just to make table markup for SO):

```py
for name, func in funcs.items():
    print(f'| {name} ', end='')
    for df in dfs.values():
        time = timeit.timeit(setup='import pandas as pd, numpy as np', stmt='res = func(df)',number=1000,globals=locals())
        print(f'| {time:.3f} ', end='')
    print('|')
```

Results were as below:

| method | zero | low | mid | high |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tdelaney | 0.846 | 0.840 | 0.830 | 0.854 |
| Goku 1 | 0.331 | 0.321 | 0.316 | 0.313 |
| Goku 2 | 0.322 | 0.299 | 0.309 | 0.326 |
| kevin41 | 0.139 | 0.140 | 0.145 | 0.138 |
| other 1 | 0.800 | 0.780 | 0.784 | 0.790 |
| other 2 | 0.821 | 0.818 | 0.816 | 0.842 |
| other 3 | 0.325 | 0.315 | 0.312 | 0.314 |

As can be seen, the answer posted by kevin41 is - *for this sample data* - more than twice as fast as the next best solution. After that, Goku's solutions, and the "other 3" solution are about equal with each other, and the last three solutions are about 2.5x slower than those.

It's interesting to note that the times for `df_low` and `df_high` are consistent for each method, suggesting that no short-circuiting is occurring.

Comment: Thanks @Nick appreciate your efforts :)

Comment: It's quite surprising to see `.any()` do this bad, considering expectation

Comment: @NikolajŠ. agreed, I would have expected `any` to peform well on the `low` case particularly.

Answer (score 1):

This function will return `True` if all values in a df are 0 and `False` if not.

```
def is_zero(df):
    vals = df.to_numpy()
    return (0 == vals).all()
```

Comment: I wonder if you can do it without `to_numpy()` -> `(df == 0).all(axis=None)`

Comment: Looks like you can, @Goku posted quite a few options

Comment: I've posted timing results for your (and other answers) in another post.

Comment: Interestingly turns out using `to_numpy` is a *good* thing

Comment: @Nick Maybe numpy's `all` is better optimized than pandas?

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Mark:

you can try:

```
(df == 0).all()

#output
Col_1    True
Col_2    True
dtype: bool
```

It will give result for individual columns like `Col_1` all are `0` ; `Col_2` all are `0`

If you do :

```
(df == 0).all(axis=None)
```

It will give for entire datframe

you can also do:

```
all((df == 0).all())
```

Comment: Using `not any()` is much better, since it would return on the first non-zero element (if any), as in @tdelaney's answer

Comment: I've posted timing results for your (and other answers) in another post.

Answer (score 1):

checkout this one:

df.isin([0]).sum()

Answer (score 1):

You could check if anything is not 0, then negate. Use the dataframe's `.any` method with axis None to check all values. This should stop on the first non-zero value which is better than `sum` or `df == 0` which will build an entire new series or dataframe.

```
not df.any(axis=None)
```

Comment: I've posted timing results for your (and other answers) in another post.